# perf broken after apt upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management

After running `sudo apt upgrade`, my `perf` was broken:

```
$ perf
/usr/lib/linux-tools/4.4.0-28-generic/perf:
error while loading shared libraries:
libbfd-2.26-system.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried to `apt remove linux-tools-common` then reinstall, to no avail.

How can this be fixed?

Using Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem. Looks like libbfd got updated but perf is still trying to link against the old version. I worked around the issue by symlinking to the library:

```
$ sudo updatedb
$ locate libbfd
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbfd-2.26.1-system.so
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbfd-2.26.1-system.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbfd-2.26-system.so
$ perf
  usage: perf [--version] [--help] [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]
..
```

Hope this helps.